# Postfix Not Sending Email to Some Addresses?

Tags: php, email, postfix

I'm using Jetpack on Wordpress, and it wasn't working. I was getting the following error:

```
Diagnostic-Code: X-Postfix; unknown user: "jake"

--60FD1138CAD.1354039466/example.com Content-Description: Undelivered Message
```

(example.com substituted for our domain)

We set up a test mail function, and that wasn't sending either. We changed the email to an outside email and it worked. Any thoughts why it won't send to an email that is at the same domain? Or why it sends to some emails but not others?

Upon running `postconf -n`, I get the following:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = example.com, Example, localhost.localdomain, localhost
myhostname = example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

Comment: The message says there is no recipient named jake.

Comment: Can you send email to `jake@example.com` from your normal email client?  And if so, does your server handle it or do you use a hosted service such as Google Apps?

Comment: so the email jake@example.com does in fact exist (I use it all the time), but when I try to send an email with the normal php "mail" function to jake@example.com it doesn't go through.  So to answer your question, the server handles it (or at least that's what I'm trying to get to work).

Comment: I wasn't very specific in my question so I will be now: do your domain's `MX` records point to your server?  We're also quite likely to want the output of `postconf -n`.

Comment: Ah, yes the MX records point to gmail, not to our server.  Above is my `postconf -n` results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I send an email to `jake@example.com`, my client looks up your MX records, finds that you are using Google and then talks directly to Google's mail servers to send the email.  My mail never ends up on your server.

When you send an email from your server to `jake@example.com` using PHP, PHP looks up its `sendmail` setting in `php.ini` and hands the mail off to that process to deliver.  In your case, that is going to be Postfix.  Since Postfix is capable of both accepting and sending emails (unlike a normal client or MUA), it first checks to see if it should accept this email itself or relay it on to some other server.  It does this by comparing the domain after the `@` symbol with the contents of the `mydestinations` config item.  In your case, this is `example.com` and it matches so your Postfix decides to accept the mail itself *instead of relaying it to Google*.  This is the root of where your problem lies.

After deciding to accept the mail itself, it then has to figure out where to put it.  This can be a virtual user table or a real Unix user or an alias to delivers to a different user (virtual or real).  In your server, none of these match.  It looks like your user account is `jakebuob`, not `jake` and you don't have any virtual maps configured.  So Postfix then bounces the message with a "User not found" message.

The easiest thing to change to fix this problem is to remove `example.com` from `mydestination`.

Comment: great, that worked!  So if I'm not planning on receiving mail at all, can I just comment that line out in my postfix config file?

Comment: No.  Any line not in the config files gets the default value.  The default value for `mydestination` includes `$hostname`. ([see here](http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html)).  Best to leave it as it is now.  You will probably want some entries in `/etc/aliases` as well to forward any local mail somewhere useful.